# Logging with logstash and logback in a docker container

Tags: java, docker, maven, logstash, logstash-logback-encoder

I will use the LogstashTcpSocketAppender in a logback configuration to send log messages to logstash. The java application works, but if I create a docker image and start the container then the messages don't arrive logstash. What can be the reason for this behavior? I wrote a sample application. You can find it [here](https://github.com/le8266/logging.problem).

**logback.xml**:

```
    <appender name="logstashAppender" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
      <destination>${destination}</destination>
      <writeBufferSize>0</writeBufferSize>

      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
          <pattern>
            <pattern>
            {
            "wps-publication": [{
              "partitionNumber": "%mdc{partitionNumber}",
              "portal": "%mdc{Portal}",
              "timestamp": "%date{ISO8601}",
              "environment": "${env}",
              "squad": "escms",
              "microservice": "wps-publication",
              "message": "%message",
              "logger": "%logger",
              "container": "pod1",
              "level": "%level"
            }]
          }
            </pattern>
          </pattern>
          <mdc/>
        </providers>
      </encoder>
    </appender>
```

I build a docker image with **docker file**:

```
   FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11-slim as builder

   WORKDIR /app
   COPY pom.xml .
   COPY src ./src

   RUN mvn package -DskipTests
   FROM openjdk:11.0.7-jre-slim
   COPY --from=builder /app/target/logging.problem-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /logging.problem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

   CMD ["java","-jar","/logging.problem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

The **docker logs** is:

```
    05:49:27,028 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
    05:49:27,028 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
    05:49:27,030 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/logging.problem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
    05:49:27,043 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@69379752 - URL [jar:file:/logging.problem-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
    05:49:27,267 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
    05:49:27,271 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [consoleAppender]
    05:49:27,280 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
    05:49:27,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.StatusListenerAction - Added status listener of type [ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener]
    05:49:27,300 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender]
    05:49:27,324 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [logstashAppender]
    05:49:27,400 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventJsonProviders] for [providers] property
    05:49:27,409 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.LoggingEventPatternJsonProvider] for [pattern] property
    05:49:27,411 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [net.logstash.logback.composite.loggingevent.MdcJsonProvider] for [mdc] property
    05:49:27,652 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
    05:49:27,652 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [consoleAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
    05:49:27,653 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [logstashAppender] to Logger[ROOT]
    05:49:27,653 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
    05:49:27,654 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@30f842ca - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
    2020-05-25 05:49:27 [main] INF logging.problem.LoggingProblemApp - Test
    2020-05-25 05:49:27 [main] INF logging.problem.LoggingProblemApp - Wait for 10 sec...
    05:49:27,695 |-INFO in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[logstashAppender] - Log destination ***:30000: connection established.
```

**Logstash config**:

```
input {
            tcp {
                port => 30000
                codec => json_lines 
                tags => ["json_lines_codec"]
            }
        }
        filter {
            split {
                field => "wps-publication"
                add_tag => ["split_json"]
                id => "split json"
            }
            date {
                match => ["[wps-publication][timestamp]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
                timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
                target => "@timestamp"
                id => "set timezone"
            }
            mutate {
                rename => {
                    "[wps-publication][environment]" => "environment"
                    "[wps-publication][squad]" => "squad"
                    "[wps-publication][microservice]" => "microservice"
                    "[wps-publication][logger]" => "logger"
                    "[wps-publication][message]" => "message"
                    "[wps-publication][container]" => "container"
                }
                id => "rename fields"
                add_tag => ["rename_fields"]
            }
            mutate {
                remove_field => [ "port", "[wps-publication][timestamp]" ]
                id => "remove fields"
                add_tag => ["remove_fields"]
            }
        }
        output {
            if "dev" in [environment] {
                elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200"]
                    index => "centralized-logging-dev-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                    timeout => 600
                }
            } else {
                elasticsearch {
                    hosts => ["***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "***:9200", "ESDEVELK16.int.cid-online.net:9200"]
                    index => "centralized-logging-invalid-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                    timeout => 600
                }
            }
        }
```

The connection is established, but logstash don't get any message. What can be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: What is your logstash config? Update your question with your logstash pipeline config.

Comment: I added my logstash config.

Comment: I cloned your project, changed the log destination to a local netcat server (`nc -lk 30001`), built the docker image, and ran the docker container, and received the log events on the netcat server side.  You could try the same thing to rule out problems with docker and logstash-logback-encoder.

Comment: I try it localy too and the server received the log events. If I try with an another encoder (LogstashEncoder) and the remote server then it works too. It seems to be the LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder. It's very strange.

Comment: When I cloned your project, it was using LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder at the time and had no problems.